# Big O proof with sqrt and log

Tags: big-o

I am having trouble figuring out how to prove that

```
t(n) = sqrt(31n + 12n log n + 57)
```

is

```
O(sqrt(n) log n)
```

I haven't had to deal with square root's in big O notation yet so I am having lots of trouble with this! Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add that tag.

Comment: not homework! just practice so i didnt think that tag was necessary, but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big O notation is about how algorithm characteristics (clock time taken, memory use, processing time) grow with the size of the problem.

Constant factors get discarded because they don't affect *how* the value scales.

Minor terms also get discarded because they end up having next to no effect.

So your original equation

```
sqrt(31n + 12nlogn + 57)
```

immediately simplifies to

```
sqrt(n log n)
```

Square roots distribute, like other kinds of multiplication and division, so this can be straightforwardedly converted to:

```
sqrt(n) sqrt(log n)
```

Since logs convert multiplication into addition (this is why slide rules work), this becomes:

```
sqrt(n) log (n/2)
```

Again, we discard constants, because we're interested in the class of behaviour

```
sqrt(n) log n
```

And, we have the answer.

**Update**

As has been correctly pointed out,

```
sqrt(n) sqrt(log n)
```

does not become

```
sqrt(n) log (n/2)
```

So the end of my derivation is wrong.

Comment: @Chris Darn. You're right. Got my operations reversed. Classic case of seeing what I wanted to, to end up at a predefined point. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: No worries. I figure it's a *big* O, so we don't have to try too hard for that last bit... sqrt(log n) is clearly smaller than log n eventually :)

Comment: sqrt(log n) = (log n)^ (1/2) = (1/2) * (log n)

Comment: @Silvia: Wouldn't that only be true if it were log(n^(1/2))?  Not (log n)^(1/2)?

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the largest-degree factor inside of the `sqrt()`, which would be `12nlogn`.  The largest-degree factor makes all the other factors irrelevant in big O terms, so it becomes `O(sqrt(12nlogn))`.  A constant factor is also irrelevant, so it becomes `O(sqrt(nlogn))`.  Then I suppose you can make the argument this is equal to `O(sqrt(n) * sqrt(logn))`, or `O(sqrt(n) * log(n)^(1/2))`, and eliminate the power on `logn` to get `O(sqrt(n)logn)`.  But I don't know what the technical justification would be for that last step, because if you can turn `sqrt(logn)` into `logn`, why can't you turn `sqrt(n)` into `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the leading terms of the expansion of sqrt(1 + x) for |x| < 1.